# Is V a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

Based on what conditions, the set $V = \{f \in C[0,1]: f(0) = a\}$ is a vector space?

I know, I need to show that for $f,g \in V$, $f+g$ is in $V$ and for $k$, $kf \in V$.
Can everyone guide me?

Comment: First of all you want that $V$ contains the 0 function.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f, g \in V$. Then $f(0) = g(0) = a$. Hence, $(f + g)(0) = f(0) + g(0) = 2a$. Furthermore, $kf(0) = ka$. But in order for this to be a vector space, both $(f + g)(0)$ and $kf(0)$ should be equal to $a$. So, we have the conditions $2a = a$ and $ka = a$. Only one value of $a$ satisfies these.